# java function getTime in xslt

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a xslt, I want to get "today + 10 years in millis"

```
    Date today = new Date();
    Date tenYears = new Date(today.getTime() + 1000*3600*24*365*10);
```

Now I want to use this in xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:java="java"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">

   <value><xsl:value-of select="java:util.Date.new()"/></value>

</xsl:template>
```

the line

```
<xsl:value-of select="java:util.Date.new()"/>
```

works, but when I try

```
<xsl:value-of select="java:util.Date.new().getTime()"/>
```

fails, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with Xalan you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java" exclude-result-prefixes="java">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <value>
            <xsl:variable name="today" select="java:java.util.Date.new()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="tenYears"
                select="java:java.util.Date.new(java:getTime($today) + 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 365 * 10)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tenYears"/>

        </value>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See the documentation at http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html#java-namespace and note that other XSLT processor implementations might have different mechanisms for calling into Java.